# PayPal cannot process this transactio​n because

Tags: html, paypal, forms

Hi I am creating a form where I want to pass the prices to paypal. I have copied one of the sauce examples but I just keep getting the above error. Does any one have any ideas?

PayPal cannot process this transactio​n because of a problem with the seller's website.

thanks in advance Mikemc.

code is below

```
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my details">

<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="my Product">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">

<!-- Provide a dropdown menu option field with prices. -->
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="test">test<br />
<select name="os0">
  <option value="1page">1 page £40.00 GBP</option>
  <option value="4page">4 page £100.00 GBP</option>
  <option value="6page">6 page £130.00 GBP</option>
 </select> <br />

<!-- Specify the price that PayPal uses for each option. -->
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="1page">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="40">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="4page">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="6page">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="130">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<br>
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

Comment: whre is your form start tag? please update code. (I see </form> but can not see <form action="action" method="post">)

Comment: sure I had copied that bit. but <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

Comment: it does say https://www.paypal etc. not sure what is up with my copy and paste